# App-Groups in App-Picker for all users

Tags: gnome, users, appmenu, 21.10

I administrate our system at school. I want to group apps by subject in the app-picker and it works fine for my admin-user. However I want to keep this layout for all users.

I tried to set up a dconf database and put the value of my current configuration in it

```
[org/gnome/shell]
app-picker-layout=myValue
```

and added a lock on that value. (As described here: [How to change default dock applications for new users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066239/how-to-change-default-dock-applications-for-new-users))

If I log in as a student or a teacher, I still see all the apps now without any groups and I am unable to change anything because of the dconf-lock.

Probably I used the wrong key for the gsettings.

Does anyone have an idea how to keep these groups for all users on the computer?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself:

First there has to be a new dconf-database located in `/etc/dconf/`.

Create the database by creating the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/dconf/profile/user
```

with the following content:

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

This shows gnome, where your settings are stored.

Next define, what your profile looks like. To do so create the following folder and file

```
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/local.d
sudo nano /etc/dconf/db/local.d/my_style
```

and put something like this in:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/app-folders]
folder-children=['myfolder']

[org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/myfolder]
name='Preferences'
apps=['app1.desktop', 'app2.desktop']

[org/gnome/shell]
app-picker-layout=[{'firefox.desktop': <{'position': <0>}>,'myfolder': <{'position': <1>}>}]
```

Then put a lock on these settings to keept the changes (however then they cannot be changed)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks
sudo nano /etc/ dconf/db/local.d/locks/mystyle
```

with the following content:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children
/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/myfolder/name
/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/myfolder/apps
/org/gnome/shell/app-picker-layout
```

Finally reload your dconf:

```
sudo dconf update
```

Login, logout. Done.